# Where can I get interesting resources on Commodities?

Tags: commodities, research

I have a reasonably good background in Quantitative Finance, but I have a small experience in the markets *themselves*.

I would like to be able to start developing my own view on the commodity markets, not only from a technical or quantitative point of view, but also from a more global and fundamental one.

I believe having a global view is not easy and that it will come with time. I started a few months ago to read the research of different banks through their monthly reviews. However, I think I should allocate some time **daily** to enhance my global knowledge in these markets.

I do not really know what to do; what newspaper(s) (if any) should I read? Which websites specialized on commodities should I monitor?

Comment: I think you are looking for advanced topics unless i am misreading but that does not come across clearly in the question.  I think you need to provide more guidance as to what you are looking to learn.  This will enable the community to provide you with better guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pretty big name news agencies which have a section dedicated to commodities:

[CNN](http://money.cnn.com/data/commodities/)

[Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/)

[Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/finance/commodities)

Comment: I think your reply is a good one and not worth a downvote.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that go through some forums where commodities topics be discussed so that if you have some issues related any point in commodities investment you will easily get your question sort out.

Comment: Forums such as?